# Swift: Reducing the length of Init methods

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9

I would like to reduce the length of init method.

```
struct Person {

    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var vehicle: String
    var location: String
    var timeZone: String

    init (id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, vehicle: String, location: String, timeZone: String ) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.vehicle = vehicle
        self.location = location
        self.timeZone = timeZone
    }
}
```

Below is an instance of `Person` I am creating.  I have to pass in the value of every single variable inline.

```
let person = Person(id: 22, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", vehicle: "Chevy", location: "Dallas", timeZone: "CST")
```

Question: How can I shrink the length of `init?`  In Obj-C I used to create a data model class.  Populate it's variables and then pass the entire class, reducing the length of the init method.

i.e.

```
Person *person = [Person new];
person.id = 22;
person.firstName = "John";
person.lastName = "Doe";
person.vehicle = "Chevy";
person.location = "Dallas";
person.timeZone = "CST"

Person *person = [Person initWithPerson:person];
```

What's an equivalent way in Swift to reduce the length of `init` without having to initialize every single variable inline?  I know tuples is one way, is there any other best practice?

Comment: doesn't just adding `init() { }` work? your variables are all optionals so they should just be set to nil if you were to call `let newPerson: Person = Person()`

Comment: structs are great because you DON'T need to create ANY initializer

Comment: Right, but I need to provide the values.

Comment: @user1107173 just delete the whole init it will work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `struct` you actually don't need an initializer

```
struct Person {
  var id : Int?
  var firstName: String?
  var lastName: String?
  var vehicle: String?
  var location: String?
  var timeZone: String?
}

var person = Person()
person.id = 22
person.firstName = "John"
person.lastName = "Doe"
person.vehicle = "Chevy"
person.location = "Dallas"
person.timeZone = "CST"
```

You can do the same with non-optionals

```
struct Person {
  var id = 0
  var firstName = ""
  var lastName = ""
  var vehicle = ""
  var location = ""
  var timeZone = ""
}
```

Consider also the benefit of an initializer to declare (read-only) constants

```
struct Person {
  let id : Int
  let firstName : String
  let lastName : String
  let vehicle : String
  let location : String
  let timeZone : String
}
```

In this case you have to use the implicit memberwise initializer.

```
let person = Person(id: 22, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", vehicle: "Chevy", location: "Dallas", timeZone: "CST")
```

Comment: Right, but you must use the implicit memberwise initializer.

Answer (score 3):

### Just remove the initializer!

```
struct Person {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let vehicle: String
    let location: String
    let timeZone: String
}
```

Now you can use the memberwise initializer

```
Person(
    id: 87112,
    firstName: "Walter",
    lastName: "White",
    vehicle: "2004 Pontiac Aztek",
    location: "Albuquerque",
    timeZone: "UTC-07:00"
)
```

> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they do not define any of their own custom initialisers.
>
> [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

### DO NOT use var

As you can see I replaced `var` with `let`.
Unless you need to change some properties of a `Person` after the value has been created, I suggest you to use `let`. Otherwise you are free to use `var`. This way the compiler will prevent unwanted changes.

### DO NOT use Optionals

I don't know the business logic of your app, however if a Person must have all that 6 properties always populated, don't make them optionals. Otherwise every time you need to use a `Person` value the compiler will force you to check if that optional has a value.

### DO NOT use Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals

Seriously. There are a few cases where they are useful and a model value is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned in the comments, an initializer will be created for you, and it'll look like this:

```
Person(id: Int?, firstName: String?, lastName: String?, vehicle: String?, location: String?, timeZone: String?)
```

However, you can also do this:

```
var person = Person()
person.id = 100
person.firstName = "Name"
...
```

Like you used to do in ObjC. Note that person was declared as `var`, because if it was declared as `let`, you wouldn't be able to mutate it.

Comment: Unless it's a `struct`